# How do I add recursive logic in resolvers using GraphQL mutations?

Tags: graphql, sequelize.js, apollo-server

Is it possible to add logic in resolvers using GraphQL mutations?

I am trying to create a four-digit string as an alias for a post if the user does not provide it. Then, I would like to check the database to see if the four-digit string exists. If the string exists, I would like to create another four-digit string recursively.

At the moment, I'm exploring adding logic to mutations within resolvers, but I'm not sure if this is doable. I'm using these documents for my foundation: [graphql.org](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/) [sequelize.org](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-finders.html)

This is my current code block:

**Working as of 12/4/2020**

```
const MakeSlug = require("./services/MakeSlug");

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    async allLinks(root, args, { models }) {
      return models.Link.findAll();
    },
    async link(root, { id }, { models }) {
      return models.Link.findByPk(id);
    }
  },
  Mutation: {
    async createLink(root, { slug, description, link }, { models }) {
      if (slug !== undefined) {
        const foundSlug = await models.Link.findOne({
          where: { slug: slug }
        });
        if (foundSlug === undefined) {
          return await models.Link.create({
            slug,
            description,
            link,
            shortLink: `https://shink.com/${slug}`
          });
        } else {
          throw new Error(slug + " exists. Try a new short description.");
        }
      }

      if (slug === undefined) {
        const MAX_ATTEMPTS = 10;
        let attempts = 0;
        while (attempts < MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
          attempts++;
          let madeSlug = MakeSlug(4);
          const foundSlug = await models.Link.findOne({
            where: { slug: madeSlug }
          });
          if (foundSlug !== undefined) {
            return await models.Link.create({
              slug: madeSlug,
              description,
              link,
              shortLink: `https://shink.com/${madeSlug}`
            });
          }
        }
        throw new Error("Unable to generate unique alias.");
      }
    }
  }
};

module.exports = resolvers;
```

This is my full [codebase](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-waterfall-yeor0?file=/src/resolvers.js).

Thank you!

Comment: no need to recursive ... do ... while?

Comment: @xadm - Thank you for the feedback. I replaced the recursion with a while loop. It's not running properly at the moment, but things are running.

Comment: This sounds terrify fundamentally and put your limit to 9999 per user or even worse if you use the post ID for all users. If possible I think you should just make another table for post and simply use the unique id start from 1 for post  and you don't need to worry about uid, just simply insert new post to the table

Comment: Depending on your create logic, it can also run into sudo infinite recursion when you keep generating existing id, never hit the empty one and hang forever.

Comment: @Yunhai - I see. Thanks for that input. I see what you're saying. In this case, I'm attempting to create an alias generator. The user will have the ability to create their own alias. If the user chooses not to create an alias, the service will create one for the user.

Comment: `sudo infinite recursion when you keep generating existing id` - I see. An infinite recursion would be a bad scenario. Maybe when the rate at which a time-intensive loop occurs, I could increase the slug from four chars to five?

Comment: @peyo then you should just make post table using `unique identifier` and start from 1000, otherwise, your solution to solve above question will always hit the `pseudo` (no sudo) infinite recursion when number is larger. Even small amount of existing ids with bad luck can cause issues. I highly suggest you don't do that if this is for real production. For personal fun then you can definitely try it out.

Comment: @Yunhai - This is more of a personal exercise. But I'm noting your point about the infinite recursion when the number is larger. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while loop solved the challenge. Thanks **xadm**.

```
const MakeSlug = require("./services/MakeSlug");

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    async allLinks(root, args, { models }) {
      return models.Link.findAll();
    },
    async link(root, { id }, { models }) {
      return models.Link.findByPk(id);
    }
  },
  Mutation: {
    async createLink(root, { slug, description, link }, { models }) {
      if (slug !== undefined) {
        const foundSlug = await models.Link.findOne({
          where: { slug: slug }
        });
        if (foundSlug === undefined) {
          return await models.Link.create({
            slug,
            description,
            link,
            shortLink: `https://shink.com/${slug}`
          });
        } else {
          throw new Error(slug + " exists. Try a new short description.");
        }
      }

      if (slug === undefined) {
        const MAX_ATTEMPTS = 10;
        let attempts = 0;
        while (attempts < MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
          attempts++;
          let madeSlug = MakeSlug(4);
          const foundSlug = await models.Link.findOne({
            where: { slug: madeSlug }
          });
          if (foundSlug !== undefined) {
            return await models.Link.create({
              slug: madeSlug,
              description,
              link,
              shortLink: `https://shink.com/${madeSlug}`
            });
          }
        }
        throw new Error("Unable to generate unique alias.");
      }
    }
  }
};

module.exports = resolvers;
```

Comment: eh... do { makeslug=MakeSlug(4); find ... } while (foundSlug!=undefined) ... link create

Comment: I see. Looks good. Keeping it consistent with the while loop. I made some edits to the code. Thank you.

Comment: eh ... only find in loop ... no attempts++

Comment: eh... still too much `while`-s ... `if ( slug` ... `if ( foundSlug === null` rather?